# Why is Eclipse giving me this annotation error on Override

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, annotations, overriding

The below code Eclipse is giving me "'hi' from class 'com.test.SubClass' does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override." error. But if I remove the @Override in the SubClass, it won't complain and treats the method as an Overriding method. Is there any way in Eclipse so I could ignore these annotation errors with generics?

```
interface Base<T extends Object> {

    void hi(T t);

}
class SubClass implements Base<String> {

    @Override
    public void hi(Object o) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
public void hi(Object o)
```

to

```
public void hi(String o) // or String s
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I don't get why removing @Override would work and it would treat it as an overriding method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention they are both Groovy classes